# Why can't I see all stats for object from Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the [Python SDK for Facebook's Graph API](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk) to fetch how many times a Facebook page has been liked.  I went to the [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to obtain an access token.  The first time I chose the "Graph API Explorer" from the drop-down menu for the Application (top-right).  I then ran this code and got back what I expected:

```
import facebook

ACCESS_TOKEN = "**********"

facebook_page_id = "168926019255" # https://www.facebook.com/seriouseats/
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)
page = graph.get_object(facebook_page_id)

print page

{u'about': u'The Destination for Delicious',
 u'can_post': True,
 u'category': u'Website',
 u'checkins': 0,
 u'cover': {u'cover_id': u'10154881161274256',
  u'id': u'10154881161274256',
  u'offset_x': 0,
  u'offset_y': 43,
  u'source': u'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-0/p180x540/13391436_10154881161274256_2605145572103420621_o.jpg'},
 u'founded': u'December 2006',
 u'has_added_app': False,
 u'id': u'168926019255',
 u'is_community_page': False,
 u'is_published': True,
 u'likes': 159050,
 u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/seriouseats/',
 u'mission': u'Serious Eats is a site focused on celebrating and sharing food enthusiasm through recipes, dining guides, and more! Our team of expert editors and contributors are the last word on all that\u2019s delicious.',
 u'name': u'Serious Eats',
 u'parking': {u'lot': 0, u'street': 0, u'valet': 0},
 u'talking_about_count': 3309,
 u'username': u'seriouseats',
 u'website': u'http://www.seriouseats.com',
 u'were_here_count': 0}
```

I then went back to the API Explorer and changed the Application to my new Facebook app that I created recently.  I generated a new Access Token, swapped it out, and ran the code above.  This is the response I get back in the `page` variable:

```
{u'id': u'168926019255', u'name': u'Serious Eats'}
```

As you can see, it only returns the `id` and the `name` of the page but the other attributes -- specifically the `likes` attribute -- are missing.

So, **do I need to give my application permissions to see all attributes for an object?**  I've tried generating an Access Token from my App Id & App Secret but still get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to look here.

1. Version of facebook API. 
   In your first example when you got lots of result, you are using **version 2.2** (that is the default version of facebook python sdk).
   When you went and created new app in facebook, it has most likely used **version 2.6** as default. Therefore, it now only returns two to three fields and the rest you need to ask for.
2. Assuming you are indeed using version 2.6, how you can ask for is

to use the following code

```
page = graph.get_object(id='168926019255', fields='about, affiliation, awards, category')
```

This will give you

```
{'id': '168926019255', 'about': 'The Destination for Delicious', 'category': 'Website'}
```

Now you want to get the likes. Since likes are not a default field but an "edge", you need to ask them using "connection". To do this, you can do the following:

```
page = graph.get_connections(id='168926019255', connection_name='likes')
```

This will now give you all the likes

```
{'data': [{'id': '134049266672525', 'name': 'Tom Colicchio'}, {'id': '143533645671591', 'name': 'Hearth'}, {'id': '57909700259', 'name': 'Toro'}, ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!  Is there any way to get the total number of users who like the page?  Using your approach I'd have to paginate through list of all users who've liked that page and add them up.  Also, it doesn't look like I can pass in another parameter to the `get_object()` method, so how would you recommend I go about getting the other attributes on the object (e.g. `founded`, `has_added_app`, `mission`, `username`, etc.)?

Comment: You can pass arguments using args. For example, `args = args = {"fields": "founded, has_added_app, mission, username"}
page = graph.get_object(id='168926019255', **args)`

Comment: Regarding likes, I can only find like summary per post in facebook by using this `168926019255_10154922404214256?fields=likes.summary(true)` and according to this format, you should be able to use this `posts = graph.get_connections(id='168926019255_10154922404214256', connection_name='likes', summary='true') which will give you `'summary': {'has_liked': False, 'can_like': True, 'total_count': 9}' before paging.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this question. I've marked your answer correct. I'm going to write a new question to specifically ask "how do I get the total count of likes for a specific page without having to paginate through a list of all users who've liked said page".

Comment: I actually found that the field name has been changed to `fan_count` for the number of people who subscribe to a certain Page.

Comment: That is a great find. I will use that too. Thank you